# Parsing Configuration file using lex and yacc

Tags: parsing, yacc, lex

```
global{
    verb 
    test 
    rl0 
    rand (or) rand =0      [Two cases]
}

thread{
    frac_value = (0.2,(0.1,0.5))
    random_thread

}
```

OUTPUT should be this:

If i give the above input to lex and yacc, based upon the checking of [ rand (or) rand=0 ]

1. if it is "rand", then it should print as " verb test rl0 rand frac_value:L=0.1 frac_value:H=0.5"
2. if it is "rand=0", then it should print as " verb test rl0 rand=0 frac_value=0.2".

For this could someone please tell me how to write a lex and yacc program.

Comment: I do not really understand what you are looking for here. I assume what you're showing is the input you want parsed? Could you be a bit more specific in how the input looks and how the desired output should look?

Comment: Input:global{
    verb 
    test 
    rl0 
    rand (or) rand =0      [Two cases]
}

thread{
    frac_value = (0.2,(0.1,0.5))
    random_thread

}
OUTPUT should be this:

If i give the above input to lex and yacc, based upon the checking of [ rand (or) rand=0 ]

if it is "rand", then it should print as " verb test rl0 rand frac_value:L=0.1 frac_value:H=0.5"
if it is "rand=0", then it should print as " verb test rl0 rand=0 frac_value=0.2".

Answer (score 1):

You ask: "For this could someone please tell me how to write a lex and yacc program"

This is a pretty broad topic, far too large to be covered in a few paragraphs on Stack Overflow. I suggest reading a book on lex and yacc, such as this one: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920002.do